# Add elements of a list based on the elements of another list

Tags: python

This is a continuation of another question I have asked before ([Dataframe add element from a column based on values contiguity from another columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63190592/dataframe-add-element-from-a-column-based-on-values-contiguity-from-another-colu)), I got the solution if I use a pandas `DataFrame`, but not if I have 2 lists, and here is where I am stuck.

I have 2 lists:

```
a=[2,3,4,1]
b=[5,6,7,2,8,9,1,2,3,4]
```

The result I would like to add the element of `b` using the value of `a`.
The first element of `a = 2` so I would like to add from `b` the first 2 elements `(5+6)`

The second element of `a = 3` so I would like to add from `b` the next 3 elements  `(7+2+8)`
and so on.

I tried `a` for loop but the sum always starts from the first element of `b`. There is a way to get the result I want without change `b` or create another list?

Comment: what's the expected output? Is it just `47` ?

Comment: You say you have 2 lists but you've tagged this with numpy. Are you working with lists or numpy arrays?

Comment: I am try to work with list, now

Comment: Result can be stored in a list c.
Result should be:
a[1]=2 output is (from the first 2 elements of b) 5+6=11
a[2]=3 output is (from the next 3 elements of b) 7+2+8 =17
a[3]=4 output is (from the next 4 elements of b) 9+1+2+3=15
a[4]=1 output is (from the next 1 element of b) 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
a=[2,3,4,1]
b=[5,6,7,2,8,9,1,2,3,4]

c = []
index = 0
for item in a:
    c.append(sum(b[index: index + item]))
    index += item
print(c)
```

Output

```
[11, 17, 15, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy:

```
import numpy as np
 
np.add.reduceat(b,np.cumsum(np.concatenate([[0],a[:-1]])))
# array([11, 17, 15,  4])
```

python:

```
import itertools as it

bi = iter(b)
[sum(it.islice(bi,x)) for x in a]
# [11, 17, 15, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `numpy.cumsum` to get a running sum of the starting index for the next series of sums. Then you can zip that index list against itself offset by 1 to determine the slice to sum for each iteration.

```
>>> from numpy import cumsum
>>> starts = cumsum([0] + a)
>>> [sum(b[i:j]) for i,j in zip(starts, starts[1:])]
[11, 17, 15, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without creating a new intermediary list, you could do something like this:

```py
[ sum( b[ sum(a[:i]): ][ :a[i] ] ) for i in range(len(a)) ]
```

Although, it is somewhat computation heavy. Using a for loop which builds the list `c` would be a much more efficient approach, like @Balaji Ambresh answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[2,3,4,1] 
b=[5,6,7,2,8,9,1,2,3,4]

new = []
i=0
for x in range(len(a)):
    el = a[x]
    new.append(sum(b[i:i+el]))
    i=i+el
print(new)

#[11, 17, 15, 4]
```